# Persistent error dialog in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent an error dialog (errordlg) to appear when an existing error dialog hasn't been attended yet. I'm developing a GUI in matlab and I can easily make 50 error dialogs to appear and collapse my task manager as it is shown in the picture.

[image: A lot of error dialogs]

On the other hand, I have seen warning or error dialogs that don't let the user to operate the GUI until he attends them. Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks in advance!
Charlie

Comment: this link might be useful: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/disable-entire-figure-window/

Answer (score 4):

If the same callback is creating the error dialog, you can prevent callback re-entrancy by inspecting `dbstack` for multiple calls to the responsible callback.  See the [`isMultipleCall` function on this blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-callback-re-entrancy/).

There is no sense to plagiarizing Yair Altman's function here, but the usage would involve putting the following line at the top of the callback that creates the errordialog:

```
if isMultipleCall();  return;  end
```

Then that callback cannot run again until you have addressed the errordialog, allowing the first call to terminate.

However, you can create your error dialog with the `'WindowStyle'` called `'modal'`, which will prevent interaction with any other MATLAB window until the dialog is closed.

Comment: 'modal' in my opinion is the proper way to go. An error-dialog should be taken care of before anything further happens...

Answer (score 3):

`errordlg` has a third argument `createmode`. One possible value is `'replace'` for which all previously open error dialogs with the same title are closed. This can be useful in your case if the 50 or so error dialogs are the same.